# Why do sins always seem delicious and attractive?

Tags: practical-islam, sin

Why do Sins always seem attractive, like its far easy to tell lie but not truth. because some time truth hurts people.

It's difficult to say prayer but easy to watch movie.

A person even try to walk on Path of ALLAH, But he find more hurdles than a person who is not on right path.

Still we say "Islam is deen-e-Fitrat" (Religion of nature).

What is the definition of Nature then ?

I try to be on right path, but cant do. Why?

Comment: i will wait for that

Answer (score 1):

To differentiate from the other answers I would put the emphasis on something else, and that is the [nafs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nafs).

I can argue if in the last instance Satan is responsible for our bad deeds, such as the decision not to do the prayer and continue being lazy. However, I believe that his "door" into us is the nafs. In the nafs Satan founds his best assistant to "manipulate" a certain person.

To add another perspective to your question; the world we are living today in some sense is designed into not allowing us to do the daily rituals (take it with some grain of salt). The dynamic nature of life and the tasks in it get us busy. On top of that, all the stuff that we are served to (via media) feed the [nafs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nafs) and its [characteristics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nafs#Characteristics_of_nafs).

Answer (score 0):

Assalamu alaikum wa rahmatullahi wa barakatuhu, dear brother.

All praises is due to Allah (SWT) blessing and salutations upon Muhammad (PBUH) and all his companions, his family members and his entire household.

- *I'm not a Muslim scholar, so some of my statements can be untrue*.
- Firstly I want to quote first 10 Ayats (verses) to the certainty of resurrection].

  3. Does man think that We will not assemble his bones?
  4. Yes. [We are] Able [even] to proportion his fingertips.
  5. **But man desires to continue in sin.**
  6. He asks, "When is the Day of Resurrection?"
  7. So when vision is dazzled
  8. And the moon darkens
  9. And the sun and the moon are joined,
  10. Man will say on that Day, "Where is the [place of] escape?"
- Why sins are so attractive? Because it is a work of Shaytan and he is trying his best. It is one of the reasons why Allah sent guidance to us. It is the Quran and Sunnah of the Prophet (PBUH). And Allah sent prophets to all nations before Muhammad (PBUH) to guide them on a true path.
- If lying and not praying is easy for you then something wrong with your Iman. For instance when some Muslims trying to lie even in small things, their tongues can't move. May Allah protect all of us from lying, may Allah grant us ease and goodness.
- Shaytan is whispering to you that prayer is so hard. But through the prayer you are building your link with Allah Almighty. What is better: to have a strong link with your Maker or having a girlfriend or good relation with your boss? A man is a complete fool if he is trying to make good link with his boss in this finite life but not trying to develop a link with his Boss in hereafter.
- Last point about hardness. Hardness is good for you! When you are starting forgetting about Allah He puts some hardness in your life for you to remind Him, to be grateful. So be grateful and keep in mind 214 Ayat from Surat Al-Baqarah:

> 214. Or do you think that you will enter Paradise while such [trial] has not yet come to you as came to those who passed on before you? They were touched by poverty and hardship and were shaken until [even their] messenger and those who believed with him said,"When is the help of Allah ?" Unquestionably, the help of Allah is near.

Wa alaikum assalam wa rahmatullahi wa barakatuhu!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very significant question which you inquired. Of course, the point is that it is not too easy to reply to your question briefly. But briefly I can tell you that Satan (Shaitan) is the main reason that make such thoughts in our mind. In fact we can say that he the means for us that Allah can test us by this.

For instance, you can read the text below (according to: [www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa1052)) which shows three ways which Satan enters...:

> 1. The beautification of ugly deeds: By making ugly actions appear beautiful, Satan effectively strips the otherwise inherent ugliness of
>      sin and mitigates the societal taboo associated with sin in such a way
>      that man easily falls into the trap of sin. This phenomenon can be
>      witnessed in a person who rationalizes his wrong actions.
> 2. False promises: Through false promises and unattainable hopes, Satan renders man heedless of the Hereafter, death, and even Allah
>      (awj). Such a person becomes a slave to his desires and is prepared to
>      go to any lengths to attain the attainable, even if it means sinning
>      against Allah (awj).
> 3. Fear: Satan scares man with thoughts of the future, compelling him to accumulate wealth, flee from jihad, aid the unjust, etc.

So I recommend you to read the following sites which are related to your question and actually could respond you.

[www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa1052)

[www.tebyan.net](http://www.tebyan.net/newindex.aspx?pid=220461)

Comment: But why Satan has so much influence on us, if we try to do good he puts more effort to divert us. if we do bad he help us to do bad. I know it happens but how we can get rid from the evil ? is it impossible so ? :O